# PHP – Slow String Manipulation

Tags: php, string, performance

I have some very large data files and for business reasons I have to do extensive string manipulation (replacing characters and strings). This is unavoidable. The number of replacements runs into hundreds of thousands.

It's taking longer than I would like. PHP is generally very quick but I'm doing so many of these string manipulations that it's slowing down and script execution is running into minutes. This is a pain because the script is run frequently.

I've done some testing and found that **str_replace** is fastest, followed by **strstr**, followed by **preg_replace**. I've also tried individual  str_replace statements as well as constructing arrays of patterns and replacements.

I'm toying with the idea of isolating string manipulation operation and writing in a different language but I don't want to invest time in that option only to find that improvements are negligible. Plus, I only know Perl, PHP and COBOL so for any other language I would have to learn it first.

I'm wondering how other people have approached similar problems?

I have searched and I don't believe that this duplicates any existing questions.

Comment: this is great question. +1 from me. I see you are using files. Can you switch to database somehow? if not can we see some data from files?

Comment: How are the strings read and handled? Have you benchmarked the string replacement vs the actual opening of files or streams? Platform?

Comment: There's nothing fancy in the files, it's just a question of replacing underscores, removing commas, replacing non-UTF8 characters etc etc.

Comment: Yes, I have benchmarked the file handling. Its takes milliseconds for open/close. Reading records from files is so quick that PHP reverts to scientific notation when records times.

Comment: Is it a must that you process each file in the same operation? I'm guessing you do not have access to the config-files and increasing the execution time?

Comment: PHP config files? Are there changes I can make to increase performance? Any links to reading material would be great, thanks.

Comment: Can you schedule it? (add some usleep to avoid bogging down the server).

Comment: No, it needs to run often during the day. It takes (dodgy) data from suppliers and updates a live DB.

Comment: Is all the data used? you could do the subsitutions just before the data is written to the database. That way you'll only be doing find/replace on data which is actually used.

Comment: Yes, I'm avoiding search/replace on fields that don't need it. That was the first thing I did when trying to improve performance.

Comment: Define *very large*: average size=?

Comment: Is your program doing the same replacements multiple times? If so, have you considered cacheing the results?

Comment: Well, 'very large' is relative but in my case I'm about multiple files, each 4,000+ records of 50+ fields per record. Not large for some people I guess.

Comment: Caching pre-processed data is an interesting option, thanks. I'll have to think about how I might be able to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, considering that in PHP some String operations are faster than array operation, and you are still not satisfied with its speed, you could write external program as you mentioned, probably in some "lower level" language. I would recommend C/C++.

Comment: before starting to write an own string replacer in C I'd take a look at existing tools like `sed`

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of handling this, IMO:

- *[easy]* Precompute some generic replacements in a background process and store them in a DB/file (this trick comes from a gamedev, where all the sinuses and cosinuses are precomputed once and then stored in RAM). You can easily run into curse of dimensionality here, though;
- *[not so easy]* Implement replacement tool in C++ or other fast and compilable programming language and use it afterwards. [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) is a good example of fast manipulation tool on big textual data sets implemented in C++.

Comment: Even if I pre-computed, wouldn't I still have to do some kind of run-time search to find the appropriate pre-computed value that I wanted for each search/replace?

Comment: @Simon Roberts, hard to say without some examples of your data and replacements you need to apply. Lets assume you have your data.csv. Then you precompute files like data-no-underscore.csv, data-no-comma.csv, data-no-umlaut.csv, data-no-comma-underscores.csv, data-no-umlaut-underscores.csv etc. The search of a needed file then is a business of concatenating, say, alphabetically sorted implosion of filters to a desired dataset name.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd allow the replacement to be handled over multiple executions, you could create a script that process each file, temporarily creating replacement files with duplicate content. This would allow for you to extract data from one file to another, process the copy - and then merge the changes, or if you use a stream buffer you might be able to remember each row so the copy/merge step can be skipped.

The problem though might be that you process a file without completing it, rendering it mixed. Therefore a temporary file is suitable.

This would allow for the script to run as many times there's still changes to be made, all you need is a temporary file that remembers which files that has been processed.

Comment: I see what you mean, but my process flow is a basic: get file -> process it -> put data in DB. I think this means that I have to process the whole file before moving on to the next step. Even if I did split the search/replace operation, I would still need to wait for all parts to complete before proceeding (I think).

Answer (score 1):

The limiting factor is about PHP rebuilding the strings. Consider:

```
$out=str_replace('bad', 'good', 'this is a bad example');
```

It's a relatively low cost operation to locate 'bad' in the string, but in order to make room for the substitution, PHP then has to move up, each of the chars e,l,p,m,a,x,e,space before writing in the new value.

Passing arrays for the needle and haystack will improve performance, but not as much as it might.

AFAIK, PHP does not have low level memory access functions, hence an optimal solution would have to be written in a different language, dividing the data up into 'pages' which can be stretched to accomodate changes. You could try this using chunk_split to divide the string up into smaller units (hence each replacement would require less memory juggling).

Another approach would be to dump it into a file and use sed (this still operates one search/replace at a time), e.g.

```
sed -i 's/good/bad/g;s/worse/better/g' file_containing_data
```

Comment: Ah, that nicely explains why searches are much faster than replacements, thanks. It's a shame I can't predict the necessary changes or I could do a search and variable re-assignment which I assume would be quicker.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do this operation only once and you have to replace with static content you can use Dreamwaver or other editor, so you will not need PHP. It will be much faster.

Still, if you do need to do this dynamically with PHP (you need database records or others) you can use shell commands via [exec](http://php.net/exec) - [google search for search-replace](https://www.google.com/search?q=shell%20command%20for%20string%20replace)

Comment: This assumes you have the files available locally.

Comment: I guess that would mean creating arrays of data to pass to external functions and parsing the returned input. Is this likely to be faster than doing it all in the PHP script in the first place?

Comment: Instead of str_replace("mike", "george", $string) you can replace an entire file; this means a lot

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have hit a wall with PHP. PHP is great, but in some areas it fails, such as processing LOTS of data. There are a few things you could do:

1. Use more than one php process to accomplish the task (2 process potentially could take half as long).
2. Install a faster CPU.
3. Do the processing on multiple machines.
4. Use a compiled language to process the data (Java, C, C++, etc)

Comment: I do know how to write multi-threaded PERL, but not PHP. Questions on that subject on this forum suggest that PHP doesn't support it and people are using workarounds splitting up files etc. Multiple machines aren't an option for me but in any case I would end up with the same problems as trying to bodge a multi-thread PHP I expect. A different language is looking like the best option for me.

Comment: PHP does't really support threads, so, to what you would do is within php do: something like `exec("php /myFile.php pram1 param2 > /dev/null 2>&1 &");` you would then get them like this in the file: `$param1 = $arg[1];`

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is why are you running this script frequently? Are you performing the computations (*the string replacements*) on the same data over and over again, or are you doing it on different data every time?

If the answer is the former then there isn't much more you can do to improve performance on the PHP side. You can improve performance in other ways such as using better hardware (SSDs for faster reads/writes on the files), multicore CPUs and breaking up the data into smaller pieces running multiple scripts at the same time to process the data concurrently, and faster RAM (i.e. *higher bus speeds*).

If the answer is the latter then you might want to consider caching the result using something like memcached or reddis (key/value cache stores) so that you can only perform the computation once and then it's just a linear read from memory, which is very cheap and involves virtually no CPU overhead (*you might also utilize CPU cache at this level*).

String manipulation in PHP is already cheap because PHP strings are essentially just byte arrays. There's virtually no overhead from PHP in reading a file into memory and storing it in a string. If you have some sample code that demonstrates where you're seeing performance issues and some bench mark numbers I might have some better advice, but right now it just looks like you need refactor your approach based on what your underlying needs are.

For example, there are both CPU and I/O costs to consider individually when you're dealing with data in different situations. I/O involves blocking since it's a system call. This means your CPU has to wait for more data to come over the wire (while your disk transfers data to memory) before it can continue to process or compute that data. Your CPU is always going to be much faster than memory and memory is always much faster than disk.

Here's a simple benchmark to show you the difference:

```
/* First, let's create a simple test file to benchmark */
file_put_contents('in.txt', str_repeat(implode(" ",range('a','z')),10000));

/* Now let's write two different tests that replace all vowels with asterisks */

// The first test reads the entire file into memory and performs the computation all at once

function test1($filename, $newfile) {
    $start = microtime(true);
    $data = file_get_contents($filename);
    $changes = str_replace(array('a','e','i','o','u'),array('*'),$data);
    file_put_contents($newfile,$changes);
    return sprintf("%.6f", microtime(true) - $start);
}

// The second test reads only 8KB chunks at a time and performs the computation on each chunk

function test2($filename, $newfile) {
    $start = microtime(true);
    $fp = fopen($filename,"r");
    $changes = '';
    while(!feof($fp)) {
        $changes .= str_replace(array('a','e','i','o','u'),array('*'),fread($fp, 8192));
    }
    file_put_contents($newfile, $changes);
    return sprintf("%.6f", microtime(true) - $start);
}
```

The above two tests do the same exact thing, but **Test2** proves significantly faster for me when I'm using smaller amounts of data (*roughly 500KB in this test*).

Here's the benchmark you can run...

```
// Conduct 100 iterations of each test and average the results
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $test1[] = test1('in.txt','out.txt');
    $test2[] = test2('in.txt','out.txt');
}
echo "Test1 average: ", sprintf("%.6f",array_sum($test1) / count($test1)), "\n",
     "Test2 average: ", sprintf("%.6f\n",array_sum($test2) / count($test2));
```

For me the above benchmark gives `Test1 average: 0.440795` and `Test2 average: 0.052054`, which is an order of magnitude difference and that's just testing on 500KB of data. Now, if I increase the size of this file to about 50MB **Test1** actually proves to be faster since there are fewer system I/O calls per iteration (i.e. *we're just reading from memory linearly in Test1*), but more CPU cost (i.e. *we're performing a much larger computation per iteration*). The CPU generally proves to be able to handle much larger amounts of data at a time than your I/O devices can send over the bus.

So it's not a one-size-fits-all solution in most cases.

Comment: Whether the values will be the same or different every time is not known, so a test each time is required. I tried evaluating before replacing after reading symcbean's answer but it actually slightly increased processing time – presumably because str_replace itself contains a match test so I was effectively testing twice.
File access time is not an issue (milliseconds). Complete files are slurped  into arrays before processing. It is array elements that are the subject of str_replace, not strings read directly from files.
Thanks for the detailed reply.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know Perl, I would suggest doing the string manipulations in perl using regular expressions and use the final result in PHP web page.

This seems better for the following reasons

1. You already know Perl
2. Perl does string processing better

You can use PHP where necessary only.

Comment: Yes, I think this will be a good option for me. I'll have to run some tests and see how much faster PERL is.

Answer (score 0):

does this manipulation have to happen on the fly? if not, might i suggest pre-processing... perhaps via a cron job.

define what rules your going to be using. 
is it just one str_replace or a few different ones?
do you have to do the entire file in one shot? or can you split it into multiple batches? (e.g. half the file at a time)

once your rules are defined decide when you will do the processing. (e.g. 6am before everyone gets to work)

then you can setup a job queue. i have used apache's cron jobs to run my php scripts on a given time schedule.

for a project i worked on a while ago i had a setup like this:

```
7:00 - pull 10,000 records from mysql and write them to 3 separate files.
7:15 - run a complex regex on file one.
7:20 - run a complex regex on file two.
7:25 - run a complex regex on file three.
7:30 - combine all three files into one.
8:00 - walk into the metting with the formatted file you boss wants. *profit*
```

hope this helps get you thinking...